# Android get last known position of Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

When the user opens up Google Maps on their phone, it immediately shows the position at which it was left during the last use. What I'd like to do is "steal" the last known position of the map from the Google Maps program that comes with the phone, and position the map in my program that way. I do not want to use the location feature. Is there any way to do this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

-tjw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to ask for permissions, but Android 2.2's [passive provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER) is supposed to return results from other providers without using the actual GPS or network itself, allowing you to piggyback of the results from Google Maps.

Comment: does this only work while google maps is open, or will it still work after it's been closed for awhile?

Comment: I think that provider gives back the last good fix from network or GPS with the appropriate original time in the location's `getTime()`, as long as there hasn't been a reboot.